# PHP 'array() image' equivalent for javascript

Tags: javascript, php, etsy

I am trying to upload image to an Etsy listing via their API v2. Their documentation have code example of image upload in PHP, in which the POST request body parameter is given like this

```
$params = array('@image' => '@'.$source_file.';type='.$mimetype);
```

How would I go about replicating this in JavaScript? I have tried sending the image blob as the image parameter but it does not seem to be working.

Edit: I am using npm oauth package. Here is my complete code that I am using to call the API.

```
var oauth1 = new OAuth1.OAuth(
        'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r%20listings_w%20listings_d',
        'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token',
        'api_key',
        'api_secret',
        '1.0A',
        null,
        'HMAC-SHA1'
      );
    oauth1.post(
    'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/915677000/images',
    req.user.etsy.oauth_token,
    req.user.etsy.oauth_token_secret,
    {
        'listing_id': 915677000,
        'image': <image has to go here>
    },
    'multipart/form-data',           
    function (e, data, response){
        if (e) console.error(e);
        // let body = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        res.redirect('/create-listings')
    });
```

Comment: Check what their API accepts the file as. So far it looks like its going to be a multipart form.

Comment: Yes, it is a multipart form.
Edit: here is the link to their API doc for image upload: 
https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/images#section_uploading_images

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear the first time. I am using npm oauth package to make the call and I can not attach the formData object to the call. It has to be a JSON object. Kindly see my edit on the post to see my complete call code. Thanks.